# Converting complex nested json to csv via pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following json file

```
{
    "matches": [
        {
            "team": "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
            "overallResult": "Won",
            "totalMatches": 3,
            "margins": [
                {
                    "bar": 290
                },
                {
                    "bar": 90
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "team": "Pune Warriors",
            "overallResult": "None",
            "totalMatches": 0,
            "margins": null
        }
    ],
    "totalMatches": 70
}
```

Note - Above json is fragment of original json. The actual file contains lot more attributes after 'margins', some of them nested and others not so. I just put some for brevity and to give an idea of expectations.

My goal is to flatten the data and load it into CSV. Here is the code I have written so far -

```
import json
import pandas as pd

path = r"/Users/samt/Downloads/test_data.json"

with open(path) as f:
    t_data = {}
    data = json.load(f)
    for team in data['matches']:
        if team['margins']:
            for idx, margin in enumerate(team['margins']):
                t_data['team'] = team['team']
                t_data['overallResult'] = team['overallResult']
                t_data['totalMatches'] = team['totalMatches']
                t_data['margin'] = margin.get('bar')
        else:
            t_data['team'] = team['team']
            t_data['overallResult'] = team['overallResult']
            t_data['totalMatches'] = team['totalMatches']
            t_data['margin'] = margin.get('bar')

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(t_data, orient='index')
    print(df)
```

I know that data is getting over-written and loop is not properly structured.I am bit new to dealing with JSON objects using Python and I am not able to understand how to concate the results.

My goal is once, all the results are appended, use to_csv and convert them into rows. For each margin, the entire data is to be replicated as a seperate row. Here is what I am expecting the output to be. Can someone please help how to translate this?

From whatever I find on the net, it is about first gathering the dictionary items but how to transpose it to rows is something I am not able to understand. Also, is there a better way to parse the json than doing the loop twice for one attribute i.e. margins?

I can't use json_normalize as that library is not supported in our environment.

[output data]

[image: 1]

Comment: Is the output data the desired result?  Why did you decide to use Pandas?

Comment: @wwii -Yes, the output is the desired result. I decided to use Pandas as it has ability to convert dicts to data and then back to csv. Upon your comment, I fiddled with using two list variables. One outside the loop, one within and it seems to do the trick. Could you please let me know if there is a better optimal way to do it without pandas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the json and csv modules: create a dictionary for each team, for each *margin* if there is one.

```
import json, csv

s = '''{
    "matches": [
        {
            "team": "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
            "overallResult": "Won",
            "totalMatches": 3,
            "margins": [
                {
                    "bar": 290
                },
                {
                    "bar": 90
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "team": "Pune Warriors",
            "overallResult": "None",
            "totalMatches": 0,
            "margins": null
        }
    ],
    "totalMatches": 70
}'''

j = json.loads(s)

matches = j['matches']
rows = []
for thing in matches:
    # print(thing)
    if not thing['margins']:
        rows.append(thing)
    else:
        for bar in (b['bar'] for b in thing['margins']):
            d = dict((k,thing[k]) for k in ('team','overallResult','totalMatches'))
            d['margins'] = bar
            rows.append(d)

# for row in rows: print(row)            

# using an in-memory stream for this example instead of an actual file
import io
f = io.StringIO(newline='')

fieldnames=('team','overallResult','totalMatches','margins')
writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(rows)
f.seek(0)
print(f.read())
```

---

```
team,overallResult,totalMatches,margins
Sunrisers Hyderabad,Won,3,290
Sunrisers Hyderabad,Won,3,90
Pune Warriors,None,0,
```

---

Getting multiple item values from a dictionary can be aided by using [operator.itemgetter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
>>> import operator
>>> items = operator.itemgetter(*('team','overallResult','totalMatches'))
>>> #items = operator.itemgetter('team','overallResult','totalMatches')
>>> #stuff = ('team','overallResult','totalMatches'))
>>> #items = operator.itemgetter(*stuff)
>>> d = {'margins': 90,
...   'overallResult': 'Won',
...   'team': 'Sunrisers Hyderabad',
...   'totalMatches': 3}
>>> items(d)
('Sunrisers Hyderabad', 'Won', 3)
>>>
```

I like to use use it and give the callable a descriptive name but I don't see it used much here on SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I now will comb through your solution to really understand what is happening. Again, as detailed in the other reply, can I make this work even if there are at least 8 more attributes after margins and different stage of nesting in them?

Comment: It can be made to work with the *more extensive* structure, you just have to work out the logic for it to parse the nested items into individual rows - might even want to use functions for parsing to separate the parsing from the logic and keep the logic *visible* if it gets too complicated.

Comment: Why not just `items = operator.itemgetter('team','overallResult','totalMatches')`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght - ?? no reason, I already had the tuple in the editor...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame` to create DataFrame and explode the `margins` column

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(data['matches']).explode('margins', ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(df)

                  team overallResult  totalMatches       margins
0  Sunrisers Hyderabad           Won             3  {'bar': 290}
1  Sunrisers Hyderabad           Won             3   {'bar': 90}
2        Pune Warriors          None             0          None
```

Then fill the `None` value in `margins` column to dictionary and convert it to column

```py
bar = df['margins'].apply(lambda x: x if x else {'bar': pd.NA}).apply(pd.Series)
```

```
print(bar)

    bar
0   290
1    90
2  <NA>
```

At last, join the Series to original dataframe

```py
df = df.join(bar).drop(columns='margins')
```

```
print(df)

                  team overallResult  totalMatches   bar
0  Sunrisers Hyderabad           Won             3   290
1  Sunrisers Hyderabad           Won             3    90
2        Pune Warriors          None             0  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh for your answer. What I had posted is a abstract version of original json. There are lot more attributes after 'margins'. In those attributes again, some are nested, some defaulted to None. Would this solution work even in that case?

Comment: @tsam1602 I think it doesn't.

Comment: I have edited the question now. Apologies, for not putting it in. Original JSON is lot more complex and I just simplified it for getting some inputs.